# Is it consistent with ZF that there is no uncountable set of algebraically independent reals?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory

Exactly what the title asks. This question was inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956506/set-of-elementary-real-numbers-without-elementary-combination) which looks for a countable such set. It is fairly easy to construct a size $\mathfrak{c}$ algebraically independent set of reals using a diagonalization of size $\mathfrak{c}$ if you have AC. What about without it though?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets See the answer, it gives an algebraically independent sets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

John von Neumann proved that $A_r = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2^{[nr]}}}{2^{2^{n^2}}}$ are algebraically independent in

> *von Neumann, J.*, [**A system of algebraically independent numbers.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01459089), Math. Ann. 99, 134-141 (1928). [ZBL54.0096.02](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:54.0096.02).

So the answer is no. It is always provable there is a set of size continuum of algebraically independent real numbers.

([Source: François G. Dorais on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23206/7206))

Comment: Wow, how does one come up with that infinite series?

Comment: He's von Neumann. He can see the matrix.

Comment: Lol. Do you have some idea how that construction works?

Comment: Mein Deutsche ist scheiße. So... no.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And also for the comment pointing to the correct post on Math overflow. I must say I'm very surprised. I assumed the answer would be Yes. Given you can't always get a vector basis. I have much more thinking to do.

Comment: Transcendence basis and Hamel basis are very different from "uncountable sets of such and such".